# Dynamic Wifi Scanner with kivy

Tags: kivy, kivymd, pyjnius

I have made a small app for Android which is responsible for scanning Wi-Fi networks, the app works well, the problem is that I don't know how to add widgets every time there is a new network.
What I want is that every time there is a new Wi-Fi network, a new widget appears with the data of that Wi-Fi network, I don't know if I explain myself, in my example I put several transparent buttons on the in which the button text is a wifi network, the bad thing about this is that when there are 4 or less wifi networks the buttons are still there, I want each new wifi network to add a button with the wifi network information,I'm still learning kivy I need help thanks!

```
import kivymd
'''
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE, Permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE, Permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION])
'''
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import jnius
from kivymd.uix.toolbar import MDToolbar
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivymd.uix.dialog import MDDialog
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.button import  MDFlatButton
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.label import Label
#from kivy.utils import platform
from jnius import autoclass

Builder.load_string('''
<Principal>:

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'WifiScan'
        pos_hint: {'center_x': .5, 'center_y': .97}
        right_action_items: [['reload',lambda x: root.wifi()]]
    MDFlatButton:
        text: 'Disabled'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .15}
        on_press:
            root.wifi() 
            root.desconecta()

        
        
    MDFlatButton:
        id: boton
        text: ''
        size_hint: 12, .10
        on_press: root.info()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .85}
        
    MDFlatButton:
        id: boton2
        size_hint: 12, .10
        text: ''
        on_press: root.info2()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .75}
        
    MDFlatButton:
        id: boton3
        size_hint: 12, .10
        text: ''
        on_press: root.info3()
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .65}
        
    
    MDFlatButton:
        id: boton4
        text: ''
        size_hint: 12, .10
        on_press: root.info3()
        user_font_size: '16sp'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .55}
        
       
    MDFlatButton:
        id: boton5
        text: ''
        on_press: root.info4()
        size_hint: 12, .10
        user_font_size: '16sp'
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .4, "center_y": .45}
        
    
        
    Label:
        id: label1
        text: "" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .85}   
            
    Label:
        id: label2
        text: "" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .75}                       
   
    Label:
        id: label3
        text: "" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .65}   
            
    Label:
        id: label4
        text: "" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .55}   

    Label:
        id: label5
        text: "" 
        pos_hint: {"center_x": .1, "center_y": .45}     
        
    
                                        
''')

class Principal(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        
        
        super(Principal, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
    try:
        
        def wifi(self):
          
            PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
            WifiManager = autoclass('android.net.wifi.WifiManager')
            activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
            service = activity.getSystemService(PythonActivity.WIFI_SERVICE)
                
            service.startScan()
                
            variable = WifiManager.getScanResults()
             
            for i in range(0,variable.size()-1):
                
                nameymac = variable.get(i).SSID+'\n'+variable.get(i).BSSID
                level1 = str(variable.get(i).level)
                chanel = str(variable.get(i).channelWidth)
                wps = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
               # wpa2 = wps.replace('WPA2', 'WPA2')
                self.Capa = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
                
                
                self.ids.label1.text = "   "+ level1#+"\n" + wpa2[1:5]
                
                self.ids.boton.text = nameymac
                
            for i in range(0,variable.size()-2):
                
                self.nameymac2 = variable.get(i).SSID+'\n'+variable.get(i).BSSID
                level2 = str(variable.get(i).level)
                self.Capa2 = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
                self.ids.label2.text = level2
                
                
                
                self.ids.boton2.text = self.nameymac2
                
                
            for i in range(0,variable.size()-3):
                nameymac3 = variable.get(i).SSID+'\n'+variable.get(i).BSSID
                level3 = str(variable.get(i).level)
                self.Capa3 = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
                
                self.ids.label3.text = level3
                self.ids.boton3.text = nameymac3
                
            for i in range(0,variable.size()-4):
                
                nameymac4 = variable.get(i).SSID+'\n'+variable.get(i).BSSID
                level4 = str(variable.get(i).level)
                self.Capa4 = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
                self.ids.label4.text = level4
                self.ids.boton4.text = nameymac4
                
            for i in range(0,variable.size()-5):
                
                nameymac5 = variable.get(i).SSID+'\n'+variable.get(i).BSSID
                level5 = str(variable.get(i).level)
                self.Capa5 = str(variable.get(i).capabilities)
                self.ids.label5.text = level5
                self.ids.boton5.text = nameymac5
          
    except:
        pass
            
        
    def desconecta(self):
        PythonActivity = autoclass('org.renpy.android.PythonActivity')
        WifiManager = autoclass('android.net.wifi.WifiManager')
        activity = PythonActivity.mActivity
        service = activity.getSystemService(PythonActivity.WIFI_SERVICE)
         
        service.disconnect()       
        service.reconnect()              
    

       
    def info(self):
        #if self.ids.boton.text != "":
        self.msg = MDDialog(
            type='custom',
            size_hint=(.9, .1),
            text=self.ids.boton.text +"\n\n"
            +"Seguridad:  \n"+self.Capa)
                    
             
        self.msg.open()
            
    def info2(self):
       # if self.ids.boton2.text != "":
        self.msg = MDDialog(
            type='custom',
            size_hint=(.9, .1),
            text=self.ids.boton2.text +"\n\n"
            +"Seguridad:  \n"+self.Capa2
                
            ) 
        self.msg.open()
            
    def info3(self):
     #   if self.ids.boton3.text != "":
        self.msg = MDDialog(
            type='custom',
            size_hint=(.9, .1),
            text=self.ids.boton3.text +"\n\n"
            +"Seguridad:  \n"+self.Capa3
                
            ) 
        self.msg.open()
            
    def info4(self):
      #  if self.ids.boton4.text != "":
        self.msg = MDDialog(
            type='custom',
            size_hint=(.9, .1),
            text=self.ids.boton4.text +"\n\n"
            +"Seguridad:  \n"+self.Capa4
                
            ) 
        self.msg.open()
            
    def info5(self):
        #if self.ids.boton5.text != "":
        self.msg = MDDialog(
            type='custom',
            size_hint=(.9, .1),
            text=self.ids.boton5.text +"\n\n"
            +"Seguridad:  \n"+self.Capa5
                
                ) 
        self.msg.open()
        
'''
    def del_widget(self):
        if self.ids.boton.text == self.ids.boton2.text or self.ids.boton =='':
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.boton)  
            
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.boton2)             
            self.ids.label1.text = ""
            self.ids.label2.text = ""
        else:
            pass   
            
        if self.ids.boton3.text ==self.ids.boton4.text or self.ids.boton3.text=='':
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.boton3)             
            self.ids.label3.text = ""
            
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.boton4)
            self.ids.label4.text = ""
        else:
            pass
            
        if self.ids.boton5.text ==self.ids.boton4.text or self.ids.boton5.text =="":
            self.remove_widget(self.ids.boton5)
            self.ids.label5.text = ""
        else:
            pass
'''
class Runnin(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Dark'
        sm = ScreenManager ()
        principal = Principal(name='principal')
        sm.add_widget(principal)
        return sm

Runnin().run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the buttons in your `kv` string with a `ScrollView` containing a `BoxLayout`, then add a button to that `BoxLayout` for each network scanned. All the buttons can have the same `on_press` method, and that method can be similar to your `info()` method. The modified `info()` method would accept an arg:

```
def info(self, text):
```

That `text` argument could be the `Button` `text` attribute, and the `info()` method could look up the information about that network in a dictionary that uses that text as the key.